# numpy angle computation using coordinates

Tags: python, numpy

I have to calculate the angle between two points say A (x1, y1) and B (x2, y2). And the current code that I am using is as follows-

```
import math
direction = math.degrees(math.atan((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)))
```

I tried performing the same code by using the following numpy code-

```
x = np.asarray(data['x'])
y = np.asarray(data['y'])

direction = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(y, x))
```

Here, 'x' and 'y' refer to two attributes having co-ordinates.

However, the values that I get for direction calculation using numpy differs from the calculations got using 'math' package.

Just to provide the min and max values-

```
data['x'].min(), data['x'].max()                                       
# (25.24, 803.85)

data['y'].min(), data['y'].max()                                       
# (21.44, 805.76)
```

The two distributions for 'x' and 'y' have an almost normal distribution.

How can I implement the angle calculation using numpy?

Thanks!

Sample data-

```
data_d = 
{'time': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
 'x': [405.31,
  405.3,
  405.29,
  405.27,
  405.27,
  405.27,
  405.31,
  405.38,
  405.46,
  405.54,
  405.63],
 'y': [417.07,
  416.86,
  416.71,
  416.61,
  416.54,
  416.49,
  416.37,
  416.27,
  416.13,
  415.93,
  415.84],
 'direction': [87.27368900609596,
  86.18592516571398,
  78.69006752595475,
  0.0,
  0.0,
  -71.56505117706985,
  -55.007979801450084,
  -60.25511870306028,
  -68.19859051363696,
  -45.00000000001809,
  -67.38013505194608],
 'direction_np_computation': [-134.1807285626706,
  -134.19444442862144,
  -134.2040441491018,
  -134.2095039258752,
  -134.21431600901414,
  -134.2177537199761,
  -134.2288323248442,
  -134.24065659640502,
  -134.2559407971113,
  -134.27535831135458,
  -134.2879109537407]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data_d)
```

Here, the column 'direction' is calculated is calculated using 'math' package and 'direction_np_computation' is calculated using the code-

```
# Reference point- Xr = 0 Yr = 0


# Get 'x' and 'y' attributes from 'data'- x = np.array(data['x']) y = np.array(data['y'])

# Compute direction from reference point with the coordinates- direction = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(Yr - y, Xr - x))
```

Why is there a mismatch between the columns?

Comment: can provide 2 concrete examples of both methods doing the same computation & the different results from each?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that it works fine. Due to the fact that I dont see the character of you numpy/pandas coordinates array I cant give you exact solution

3 versions:

arctan

```
>>> direction = np.rad2deg(np.arctan((2-1)/(2-1)))
>>> direction
45.0
```

math

```
>>> direction = math.degrees(math.atan((2 - 1) / (2 - 1)))
>>> direction
45.0
```

arctan2

```
>>> direction = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2((2-1),(2-1)))
>>> direction
45.0
```

**With fake data (as I dont see your data), using your function,**

reference point:

```
>>> Xr = 10
>>> Yr = 10
```

Check direction towards reference point with these coordinates:

```
>>> Xs = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> Ys = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

I am expecting all of them to have direction of 45 degrees

```
>>> direction = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(Yr-Ys,Xr-Xs))
>>> direction
array([45., 45., 45., 45., 45., 45.])
```

**EDIT**

Based on your provided data:

It seems you were correct with the notion that there is different result.

More in here: [numpy arctan2 bug or usage issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308639/numpy-arctan2-bug-or-usage-issues)

using np.arctan should be OK

*numpy module*

```
>>> direction = np.rad2deg(np.arctan(data.y/data.x))
>>> direction
0     45.819271
1     45.805556
2     45.795956
3     45.790496
4     45.785684
5     45.782246
6     45.771168
7     45.759343
8     45.744059
9     45.724642
10    45.712089
dtype: float64
```

*math MODULE*

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     math.degrees(math.atan((data.y[i]) / (data.x[i])))
... 
45.81927143732942
45.805555571378584
45.79595585089821
45.79049607412479
45.78568399098587
45.782246280023934
45.771167675155795
45.75934340359498
45.744059202888714
45.72464168864543
>>>
```

**NOTE**

Be careful about sign +-. Y2-Y1/X2-X1 vs Y1-Y2/X1-X2 can give different result, but in really both correct. In our case, these results are 45 deg or -135 deg. They both are correct, just one of them is clockwise